# Create a backup without a transaction log

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-backups, ssms

I have been given a backup of a SQL Server 2008 database in the form of a 150mb .bak file.

When I attempt to restore it to another server it attempts to secure 170gb+ of data, I am assuming this is due to a completely unreasonable transaction log size.

Unfortunately I do not have that much space on my VM to just restore it, so I have restored it on my local machine and after 3 or so hours of "100% complete, loading" it has finally restored.

So... the question is, how do I make another backup of this DB WITHOUT THE TRANSACTION LOG on SQL Server Management Studio Express 2014?

Comment: Switching to simple recovery mode and issuing `sbcc shrinkfile` with the log file identifier should do the trick. Then you will be able to set a reasonable log size and perform a backup.

Comment: I am going to need more information than that

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189272.aspx and then http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/ms189493.aspx .There might be implications which aren't apparent from your OP, so reading these articles (at least) in full should do no harm.

Comment: I just needed to change to simple recovery mode, your sbcc shrinkfile suggestion is what threw me and was not required. Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[image: Change db recovery mode to simple]

Fixed by changing the Recovery Mode to simple, dropped the 170gb transaction log to 1.5mb. Thanks @Ennor

Comment: So is possible to do that for backup and then change it back to full?

Answer (score 1):

First set your database Recovery model Parameter to **Simple** as @mansonitefirefox suggested in the above screenshot.

Than, if you have the possibility of Detaching the database for just a moment, using **Microsoft SQL Management Studio** you could **Detach** the database from the Microsoft SQL Serveur instance, go the folder that contains your sql **MyDataBase.mdf** file (something like D:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA) and erase the **MyDataBase_log.ldf** file that's just beside the **MyDataBase.mdf** file. Than **Attach** the database back again (During the Attach process, you will see a little table with the first line being your MyDataBase.mdf file and the second line being your MyDataBase_log.ldf. Erase the MyDataBase_log.ldf before finishing the attach process. The Server will than re-create a new and very small MyDataBase_log.ldf and log file).